# нажатие кнопки keybd_event в с++

Tags: c++, winapi

Вот есть простейший код нажатия на кнопку.
Он везде работает, в любом приложении начинает прожиматься кнопка.

```
#include <windows.h>
void main()
{
    keybd_event(0x33, 0, 0, 0);
    Sleep(10);
    keybd_event(0x33, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

кроме одного конкретного приложения, это игра.
Есть другие способы отправлять нажатия клавиш?

как вообще так может происходить, что стандартные нажатия клавиш которое обрабатывает Windows как-то по разному интерпретируются в приложении, где про это можно почитать?

может есть другие библиотеки обработки нажатий? или как можно еще отправить нажатие кнопки в игру.

Comment: Игры используют библиотеку DirectInput для обработки ввода.

Comment: вы не подскажите, я смогу с помощью этой библиотеки отправлять нажатия кнопок в игру? посоветуете какие функции конкретно изучать, по типу keybd_event из WinAPI ?

Comment: Точно не знаю. Функция `keybd_event` создаёт событие на уровне операционной системы, а библиотека DirectInput работает напрямую с драйвером устройств ввода. Попробуйте сами поизучать.

Comment: @maestro я не нашёл в библиотеке DirectInput интерфейсов для отправки команд на устройства. она только считывает. возможно и название отсюда) "Input". А мне не нужно считать клавишу, мне нужно её нажать. 
Нужно както отправить команду в буфер, откуда уже DirectInput уже обработает её для себя

Comment: задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос. уже по поводу отправки нажатий клавиш в directx.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, я недели 2 гуглил по етому вопросу. скорее всего нет программного решения. В DirectInput нельзя положить команду никак, он только читает. Читает напрямую с девайсов. Тоесть, или физически сделать устройство с прерываниями, на базе Andurino например или внедрятся в DLL конкретной программы, куда нужно слать команды.